# Iterate through nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

How would I go about iterating through a nested HashMap?

The `HashMap` is setup like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Student>>
```

Where `Student` is an object containing a  variable `name`. If for instance my HashMap looked like this (the following is not my code, it's just to simulate what the contents of the hashmap could be)

```
 hm => HashMap<'S', Hashmap<'Sam', SamStudent>>
       HashMap<'S', Hashmap<'Seb', SebStudent>>
       HashMap<'T', Hashmap<'Thomas', ThomasStudent>>
```

How could I iterate through all of the single letter keys, then each full name key, then pull out the name of the student?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Student>> letterEntry : students.entrySet()) {
    String letter = letterEntry.getKey();
    // ...
    for (Map.Entry<String, Student> nameEntry : letterEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        String name = nameEntry.getKey();
        Student student = nameEntry.getValue();
        // ...
    }
}
```

...and the `var` keyword in Java 10 can remove the generics verbosity:

```
for (var letterEntry : students.entrySet()) {
    String letter = letterEntry.getKey();
    // ...
    for (var nameEntry : letterEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        String name = nameEntry.getKey();
        Student student = nameEntry.getValue();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect and best code for traversing HashMaps of HashMaps. Thanks Brett

Answer (score 14):

Java 8 lambdas and [`Map.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) make [bkail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188550/3614835) more concise:

```
outerMap.forEach((letter, nestedMap) -> {
    //...
    nestedMap.forEach((name, student) -> {
        //...
    });
    //...
});
```

Comment: This `Map.forEach` is the most concise for the OP, but in my case, I needed to modify map values in-place so I had to use the `for(var entry : entries.entrySet())` form.